# hide pid when a process is launched in background

Tags: linux, vnc, pid

So I put this command vncconfig -iconic &, this causes vncconfig window to launch and terminal will display like [1] 13488. I want to hide this pid info.

That is, when we put the command, only vncconfig window should launch and terminal shouldn't display any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sh -c "vncconfig -iconic &"
```